# Unity - What is efficient way for sending multiple requests at the same time? WWW kills performance (FPS 120 -> 9)

Tags: android, multithreading, performance, networking, unity-game-engine

My VR app is reading JSON feed and displays it's items as game objects. Each item (10-50 item) contains url with image (1280x800 png) used as texture.

I have to send request for (10-50) images and create textures when I receive responses. This is killing my game performance. It blocks UI completely. It can't render even background sky.

It is slow in editor but worse on Android as my target platform.

Can this be done in background? Can I somehow send multiple request as a more efficient batch? Thanks in advance.

---

Details:

I'm building game object for each cards by initializing it from prefab. During build I'm filling properties and requesting it's texture. Code doing that:

```
private void moveModelToControl(List<Cards> cards){
    cards.ForEach(c => loadImage(c));
}
private void buildCardGO(c) {
    // 1.  Init game object from prefab 
    // 2. Set properties
    // 3. Ask for image/texture
    loadImage(c);
}

private void loadImage(Card c) {
    ImageLoader imgLoader = new ImageLoader();
    imgLoader.loadImage ();
}
```

where getting images from internet is done using WWW and Coroutine

```
public class ImageLoader {

     private readonly Card card;

     public ImageLoader(Card card) {
         this.card = card;
     }

     public void loadImage(){
         WWW www = new WWW(card.url);
         StartCoroutine(WaitForImage(www, onOkAction, handleError));
     }

     private IEnumerator WaitForImage(WWW www, Action<WWW> onOkAction, Action<WWW> onErrorAction) {
         yield return www;

         if (www.error == null) {
             onOkAction (www);
         } else {
             onErrorAction (www);
         }
     }

     private void onOkAction(WWW www) {
         Texture2D texture = new Texture2D (2, 2, TextureFormat.DXT1, true);
         www.LoadImageIntoTexture (texture);
         Sprite newImage = Sprite.Create (texture, new Rect (0, 0, (int)texture.width, (int)texture.height), Vector2.zero);
         card.sprite = newImage;
     }

     private void handleError(WWW www) {
         ///handle error ....
     }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use coroutine  or threads to not freeze your UI.

```
public void loadImage()
{
    StartCoroutine(GetImages(onOkAction, handleError));
}

IEnumerator GetImages() 
{
    WWW www = new WWW(card.url);
    StartCoroutine(WaitForImage(www, onOkAction, handleError));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I worked on same kind of thing earlier, By looking at your code structure I can tell that the performance problem is not entirely caused by www requests.

**First thing first**

This might just be a typo: you are not passing the card object in constructor when you create `ImageLoader` instance. How is it possible to work in this way? which card object you are using to load image for?

Now if we look at the other piece of code that you shared:

1. You are creating instance of `ImageLoader` class for every card object ( lets say you have 50 objects) which will cause garbage collector to run more frequently resulting in FPS drop. What you can do instead is create a `Monobehaviour`, may name it `DownloadManager`, place it in scene and use it to download all the stuff.
2. Considering same point, do not create a lot of local variables if you are using them just to hold temporary values. For example `Texture2D texture = new Texture2D (2, 2, TextureFormat.DXT1, true);` this texture can be created globally to avoid GC. same with sprite object in `onOkAction` method.
3. Do one thing at each step. If you are downloading images and creating sprites and instantiating it on same time it will result in bad performance (Note: creating/instantiating objects is an expensive process). You can do all the things in this flow: i) Download JSON data. ii) parse it in your data structure. iii) then download textures from URLs. iv) then create objects.
4. I would advise you to show a loading bar while you download textures in background.
5. In this scenario, use `for loop` instead of `for-each` [for better performance.](http://www.dotnetperls.com/for-foreach)

Here is sample code:

```
class DownloadManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    WWW www = null;

    public void DownloadImages(List<Card> cards)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < cards.Count; i++)
        {
            StartCoroutine(DownloadImage(cards[i]));
        }
    }

    IEnumerator DownloadImage(Card card)
    {
        www = new WWW( card.url );

        yield return www;

        if (www.error != null)
        {
            Debug.LogError("Error downloading image: " + www.error);
            // fire OnError event here.
            yield break;
        }

        card.textureData = new Texture2D(www.texture.width, www.texture.height, TextureFormat.ARGB32, false);
        www.LoadImageIntoTexture(card.textureData as Texture2D);
        www.Dispose();
    }
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for answer. Looks like you are doing basically the same thing. 
I agree about small improvements for GC but it is keeping low performance.

This will also start all frames (from Coroutine) at the same time and build textures when receive image responses.
Sending all those requests, or building all those textures will kill FPS. 
If I'm not wrong.

Comment: Code example that i posted is only one part (downloading data using coroutines) of it. You need to do all the steps in sequence rather than doing everything at once. So its not the same thing.

Comment: I've tried that, according to your steps. Thanks. 
Yes, it will keep FPS high, but complete load process will take more time. 
About 2/3 times more time.

Comment: That shouldn't be a problem. Use loading screen at start for that. All VR apps out there have same behaviour.